# Selecting MAX over multiple dependent fields

Tags: abap, opensql

Here's a sample of the data I wish to select from in the `AFRU` table.

```
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+
| Confirmation (RUECK) | Counter (RMZHL) | Finish Execution (IEDD) |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+
|                30116 |               1 | 08/26/2014              |
|                30116 |               2 | 08/27/2014              |
|                30116 |               3 | 09/27/2013              |
+----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+
```

Given this data set, I'd like to select the last row because it contains highest `RMZHL` value (I'm really only after the `IEDD` value of that record). Here's the code I've been trying to use:

```
SELECT MAX( rmzhl ), iedd FROM afru
                          INTO (@DATA(lv_rmzhl), @DATA(lv_iedd))
                          WHERE rueck = '0000030116'
      GROUP BY rmzhl, iedd.
      ...
      <some fancy code here>
      ...
ENDSELECT.
```

However, this selection always nets me the values `1` for `lv_rmzhl`, and `20140826` for `lv_iedd`, therefore not getting the `MAX` value like I'm attempting to get. I understand that his could be easily accomplished by putting it all into an internal table and sorting on the `RMZHL` field, but I'm looking for a more proper way.

Comment: Do you just need the max value of `RMZHL` for each `RUECK` or do you need additional payload data (like `IEDD`)?

Comment: @vwegert technically, all I need is the `IEDD` value `20130927`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do a subselect like:

```
SELECT SINGLE iedd
  FROM afru
  INTO @DATA(lv_iedd)
  WHERE rueck = '0000030116'
    AND rmzhl = ( SELECT MAX( rmzhl ) FROM afru WHERE rueck = '0000030116' ).
```

I've used this in a lot of cases even in combination with `FOR ALL ENTRIES` and the performance difference is very low.

Comment: just to double check, this has to be a `SELECT SINGLE`, correct?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would have to switch to `SELECT ... INTO TABLE`. I edited my answer

Comment: @gkubed Thanks for your advice. You are right - this wouldn't have compiled without whitespaces between the parentheses and `rmzhl`. It really annoys me, that people who haven't programmed in ABAP once were allowed to reject your edit on this post...